# How is it possible to make a bit by bit copy of a hard drive while using it?

Tags: forensics

I learned in forensics you can deploy an agent to a remote computer and have it retrieve an exact copy of the remote hard drive, including unallocated space and swap, even while it is being used. This copy gets sent to your pc over the internet by the agent and then you can work on it on your pc.

An example of such software is EnCase.

However, I dont understand how this is possible. If the computer is being used aren't some parts of it innacessible, such as the file with the SAM hashes in Windows? Or what if changes are made to files while the agent is copying them?

Comment: On a Windows OS machines (and apparently, Samba servers), this is done through the Volume Shadow Copy Service, VSS, which takes a snapshot of the drive. Yes, the data on the drive may change, but the snapshot is invariant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy. For other OS, though, there would need to be an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

There are actually two schools of thought in regard to forensic disk imaging.

The *oldschool* method was to unplug the PC *immediately*, and image the drive in *that state*, to ensure that nothing got changed. It also assured a certain degree of plausible deniability...

And that didn't really work too well the moment folks realised you could encrypt a drive with a password.

While *live* forensic capture doesn't ensure that *nothing* at all is *ever* altered, with proper logging, you know what the examiner has done. It's also handy since if the suspect hasn't locked his system you can probably get enough data copied out to work out what's happening.

> I learned in forensics you can deploy an agent to a remote computer and have it retrieve an exact copy of the remote hard drive, including unallocated space and swap, even while it is being used. This copy gets sent to your pc over the internet by the agent and then you can work on it on your pc.

Feels like you're confusing both processes - you'd *either* run an agent and other tools on a livedisk, or pull the hard drive to image in the 'traditional' methods, or use live tools, or good old investigative work on a running system. You can't really get a proper forensic duplicate on a running system.

[EnCase](https://www.guidancesoftware.com/encase-forensic), for example, lets you work on a VHD or VMDK made with another tool - but you aren't going to run it directly on a system being investigated.

Answer (score -1):

The goal isn't to create a perfect image of the drive, but a reasonable copy of the important data, that is, user data.  If the drive is accessed using low-level disk commands, not file system commands it can workaround issues such as file locks and open files. But those are likely OS files not user data. 
The bottom line is that the data you are interested in is usually at rest on the disk even when the system is running.

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly and why it works, etc. You know, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state and why it is.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, In some cases you have to have a physical link to the device, and permission. If not you will need hash sets and a court order. Careful.. this is wiretapping

Comment: You can emulate a HD or computer with forensic software. You can do this with a hard link or over the network. Deploying an agent requires permission. If you have no permission, you need encryption keys { hash sets ]  and a court order as this is wiretapping.

Comment: I won't give more specific info as this would be irresponsible as it aids in hacking.

Comment: What is being asked by the author isn't considered wiretapping in the security world.

Comment: @PatrickJoseph This question is asking how it's done, not how to do it. Your answer doesn't provide anything useful to OP. It's not considered hacking in this case. I'm sure OP knows the legal dangers of doing so, as they learned this in forensics CLASS. They are receiving an education on this exact topic. They know what you need, they just want to know how these softwares are able to access stuff that an OS would stop them from accessing.

Comment: Disagree, Asking what changes are made will indicate what traces to look for. OP indicated EnCase .. https://www.guidancesoftware.com/encase-forensic.  This is not a remote operation software for a nework. It is Forensic software and is meant to hack, carve, and extract data to investigation. If  OP had a class, why no ask in class?